# Delete from stu where region = ?1

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

`delete from stu where region = ?1`

Can anyone help me to understand this query?

`=?` (what type of data,it will fetch)

Comment: It is likely a parameterized query, what library/language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a parameterized query. `?1` is a parameter that need to be provided when executing the query.

Since it is a delete query it doesn't fetch anything.
The expression `region = ?1` matches those rows where the value of region is the same as the value provided for the parameter.

How you provide the parameter depends on the environment you are working in.
Most of the time you encounter this kind of construct when using SQL in other general purpose languages like C, Python, or Java.